# Conditional LINQ query in foreach

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a multiselection box and I would like to iterate over the selected items and do a linq query, but I'm not sure how to write it.  This is what I have so far:

```
if (lbStateLegislation.Items.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (ListItem li in lbStateLegislation.Items)
    attributes = vdc.attributes.Where(a => a.fieldvalue == li.Value).ToList();
}
```

I basically need to construct an OR query, so it is selecting from the collection where there are values for each of the selected items.  I think, as it's written now, it is doing an AND query.

Comment: Note that you reassign a new value in each iteration in foreach statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Contains extension method.  Linq2Sql will translate it as an IN clause:

```
var inValues = lbStateLegislation.Items.Select(s => s.Value);
vdc.attributes.Where(a => inValues.Contains(a.fieldvalue));
```

You may be able to combine the two statements into one, but I will leave that for you to try as I'm not positive that it will work as a single statement.

HTH

Comment: I had to modify the first line to be: var inValues = lbState.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(s => s.Value); but the 2nd lines gives me 0 results.

Comment: Not surprised that you had to change the first line, because lbStateLegislation probably doesn't implement the generic IEnumerable.  Have you taken a look at SQL profiler to see what the resulting SQL is?  Also, you may need to run .ToList() or .ToArray against inValues.  If that works out, let me know and I'll update my answer so it is more accurate.

Comment: You code works fine, I was querying the wrong collection. :)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var attributes=
  vdc.attributes.Where(q=> 
                   lbStateLegislation.Items.Any(o=> o.Value == q.fieldValue))
                 .Select(o=> o);
```